# ABCPdf - Image not a suitable format

Tags: image, asp.net-core, abcpdf

In the end, my goal is to send a raw image data from the front-end, then split that image into however many pages, and lastly send that pdf back to the front-end for download.

But every time I use the `theDoc.addImageFile()`, it tells me that the "Image is not in a suitable format". I'm using this as reference: https://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/source/5-abcpdf/doc/1-methods/addimagefile.htm

To troubleshoot, I thought that the image might not be rendering correctly, so I added a File.WriteAllBytes to view the rendered image and it was exactly what I wanted, but still not adding to the PDF. I also tried sending the actual path of a previously rendered image thinking that the new image might not have been fully created yet, but it also gave me the same error. Lastly, I thought PNGs might be problematic and changed to JPG but it did not work.

Here is the code:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult PrintToPDF(string imageString)
{
    // Converts dataUri to bytes
    var base64Data = Regex.Match(imageString, @"data:image/(?<type>.+?),(?<data>.+)").Groups["data"].Value;
    var binData = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Data);

    /* Ultimately will be removed, but used for debugging image */
    string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    string imgName= "Test.jpg";
    string filename = Path.Combine(path, imgName);

    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filename, binData);
    /***********************************************************/

    using (Doc theDoc = new Doc())
    {
        // Using explicit path
        theDoc.AddImageFile(@"C:\Users\User\Documents\Test.jpg", 1);
        // Using variable
        //theDoc.AddImageFile(filename, 1);
        // What I really want
        //theDoc.AddImageFile(binData , 1);

        theDoc.Page = theDoc.AddPage();
        theDoc.AddText("Thanks");
        Response.Headers.Clear();
        Response.Headers.Add("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=test.pdf");
        return new FileStreamResult(theDoc.GetStream(), "application/pdf");
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of ABCpdf are you using?

Comment: @PGTips we've since been using DinkToPDF to render PDFs but looking at my commits, we were using ABCpdfCORE Ver. 11.2.3

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (not tested, but cleaned up from my own code):

```
    public int AddImageFile(Doc doc, byte[] data, int insertBeforePageID)
    {
        int pageid;

        using (var img = new XImage())
        {
            img.SetData(data);

            doc.Page = doc.AddPage(insertBeforePageID);
            pageid = doc.Page;
            doc.AddImage(img);
            img.Clear();
        }
        return pageid;
    }
```

Comment: Wasn't able to test this since we opted for a different solution (DinkToPDF). I'll see if I can revert back to that branch sometime. But from what I've tried, wrapping the image into a `using` block is something I haven't tried so maybe this will work.

Comment: I think the bigger thing is to use an XImage() to add it to the doc. I use this code to convert TIFF scans to PDFs.

Answer (score 0):

To add a JPEG from a byte array you need Doc.AddImageData instead of Doc.AddImageFile. Note that AddImageFile / AddImageData do not support PNG - for that you would definitely need to use an XImage. The [XImage.SetData](https://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/default.htm?page=source%2F5-abcpdf%2Fximage%2F1-methods%2Fsetdata.htm) documentation has the currently supported image formats.